# How to find element in array according to some field (without scanning the entire array with for loop )

Tags: c++, c++17

I have some struct with 4 fields 
I keep 100 instance of this struct in some array (not map) and I want to find 
some element in the array according to specific field

I can scan all but I can using maybe `std::find` or some other way (I know that the find scan all the array, but I think it will be simple to use find.)

The code:

```
struct MyElement 
{
    std::string val1;
    std::string val2;
    std::string val3;
}

std::array<MyElement, 100> _myArray;


// need to find the first element that the val2 is 'Go' 
bool found = false; 
for(int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)
{
    if(_myArray[i].val2 == 'Go')
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @P.W : ok .. but how to make the look for only val2 value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sequence of `MyElement` instance is not sorted, there is nothing you can do to avoid linear scanning for a particular object. `std::find_if` is your friend here, you can use it to avoid the handwritten loop, and it stops at the first match. Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

std::array<MyElement, 100> _myArray;

_myArray[50] = { "...", "Go", "..." };

const auto lookup = std::find_if(_myArray.cbegin(), _myArray.cend(),
    [](const MyElement& e){ return e.val2 == "Go"; });

assert(lookup == _myArray.cbegin() + 50);
```

If you need to lookup elements repeatedly, it might be advantageous to sort the sequence first and then use binary search:

```
const auto binaryPred =  [](const MyElement& e1, const MyElement& e2){
     return e1.val2 < e2.val2;  };

std::sort(_myArray.begin(), _myArray.end(), binaryPred);

const auto fasterLookup = std::lower_bound(_myArray.cbegin(), _myArray.cend(), "Go",
        [](const MyElement& e, const auto& value){ return e.val2 == value; });
```

But whether that pays off or not can't be predicted without knowing the exact scenario. If unsure, measure both approaches.